# Getting Number of questions asked

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any API for getting number of questions asked in stack exchange site with respect to Tag (or Tags) ?
I would like to make small analysis on each of the tags.
Suggest me some better way to do that.

Comment: Clicking on the tag presents on the right the number of questions tagged as such. I suppose you could write (or someone has already) a script for the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name

The `count` value in the returned tag object is the question count.